# Best online community for Lego Builders?

Tags: lego-group

It seems like different people use different online communities to share Lego-related things, but is there one that's just the best? I suppose I am asking a subjective question, but what I'm looking for is:

1. Ability to easily share photos
2. Ability for others to easily comment about the photo (ideally *on* the photo)
3. Ability to form sub-groups within community (eg, "My Family," "SoCal Builders," etc)
4. Easy to find and follow fellow builders

I know Flickr *used* to allow commenting on photos, but it's such a generic photo-sharing place that unless you know who to follow, it's hard to find new/expert builders...

Answer (score 2):

I would still recommend Flickr as the number one place. It allows everything you mentioned, and the most important thing is that's where most LEGO fans and all the best LEGO builders hang out. It is by far the best community. Just join some of the main LEGO related groups and you will quickly find people to follow.

Also, follow the Brothers Brick blog. Pretty much everything they feature is from Flickr, and they focus on the best MOCs. This is another way to find great builders to follow.

There is also MOCPages, and there are some great gems there, but the site is mainly full of little kids. AFOLs and serious builders hang out on Flickr. It may not be all LEGO related, however once you become part of the LEGO related groups, you will have some much to do, so much to see, and so many people to interact with, you won't even notice that Flickr is not all about LEGO...(c:

Comment: Thanks, BrickBlogger. QQ: do you think the new Flickr enhances or takes away from the experience (compared to the previous version)? I heard some people were not happy that they removed the commenting-on-photo feature...

Comment: You can still comment right on the photos just fine. Just put your mouse over the picture and a little box will open up, drag it wherever you want it, and you can add your note. It works the same way as before. ;)

Comment: Have you used the new Flickr interface? There's no way to allow you to add comments directly into the photo itself. From what I've heard, many lego builders were pretty peeved by this feature removal...

Comment: I use the new Flicker and personally, I like it. I don't think people need to be able to comment on the photo themselves. I remember that on the old Flicker, someone would always put a giant comment over the entire photo and cover up all of the other comments. Sure, the comments directly on the photo are good for pointing out cool parts, but I don't think it was a very good feature.

Comment: @Gabe - That's funny. I guess they rolled out (or more accurately; taken away) that feature greadually, because I was still able to use commenting just fine when I first responded to your question. But I just checked again and now I can't...)c:

Comment: Okay, I just checked again and this is really weird; there are pictures where I can directly comment on the photo, and there are some where I can't. So I think this is controlled by the person who uploads the photo. I haven't uploaded anything for a while, so I'm not sure, but the point is there are definitely photos I can comment on. And not just old ones, but newly uploaded ones as well.